# python requests.get error message

Tags: python

```python
import requests

number = requests.get("http://chainz.cryptoid.info/cure/api.dws?Key=3972cc3ec73f&q=getbalance&a=BMBGZdp8cB9gi2hgxJFBTyxgUZcL6aw6B")

print number.text
```

---

Newbie question but

I can't seems to get the number I get error 403

Comment: Works for me. Can you actually open the link in your browser?

Comment: yes I can open the link in my browser but in python it prints <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /cure/api.dws
on this server.</p>
</body></html>

Answer (score 0):

if it's working in your browser, but getting 403 from python, I'm guessing you may have some proxy setting, otherwise this code should work just fine.

if you are behind a proxy, you need to configure the requests module to know about it

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "http://10.10.1.10:3128",
  "https": "http://10.10.1.10:1080",
}

requests.get("http://chainz.cryptoid.info/cure/api.dws?Key=3972cc3ec73f&q=getbalance&a=BMBGZdp8cB9gi2hgxJFBTyxgUZcL6aw6B", proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: thanks I'm using codeacademy probably they have a proxy